# Is AWS EC2 c5.2x a shared CPU from a large CPU?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS says its C5.2x has 8 vCores, C5.4x has 16 vCores, and its C5.9x has 36 vCores.

On a C5.2x box, its CPU info says the following:

```
~# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               3000.000
BogoMIPS:              6000.00
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              25344K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

On a C5.4x box, its CPU info says the following:

```
~# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               3000.000
BogoMIPS:              6000.00
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              25344K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
```

On a C5.9x box, its CPU info says the following:

```
~# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                36
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-35
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    18
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3000.004
BogoMIPS:              6000.00
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              25344K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-35
```

We can see they all have the same CPU type Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz wit the same L1/2/3 cache.

I guess c5.2x and C5.4x are 'virtual CPUs' on a large CPU like c5.9x. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, depending on your definition of "shared."

Across all current-generation EC2 instance types, the CPU capacity is spec'ed as "vCPU," where:

> Each vCPU is a thread of either an Intel Xeon core or an AMD EPYC core, except for T2 and m3.medium.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

The Xeon Platinum 8124M is an 18-core (36 thread) processor.  Instances smaller than c5.9xlarge are allocated a subset of the cores on one physical processor.  The virtualization layer reports the allocated number of cores.

But they are not "shared" in the sense of oversubscription.